# Fundamentals of electrostatics

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrostatics

Suppose I have a Gold Leaf Electroscope and the leaves are observed to diverge by a certain amount. Now if I send a beam of X-rays and allow it to fall upon the electroscope for a very short period of time, what exactly will happen?

Answer (score -1):

" By using a specially calibrated microscope to observe the movement of the strips, a scientist can measure the voltage of the charge in microvolts (millionths of a volt). When the electrical capacities of both the electroscope and the body producing the charge are known, electric currents moving through ionized air can be measured. Even when the capacities are not known, these currents can be detected. Therefore, the electroscope is used for detecting X rays, cosmic rays, and radiation from radioactive material. These rays ionize the air and pass through it as a kind of electric current. The current either charges or discharges an electroscope. "